# How to maximum size without exceed the size?

Tags: css

I'm trying to do [image: this], and I only succeed to do [image: this].

Here is the HTML code :

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="list-green scoutcondensedregular">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="list-green scoutcondensedregular">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="list-green scoutcondensedregular">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="list-green scoutcondensedregular">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div><!-- .container -->
```

And the CSS code :

```
.pairing-prosecco-wines .list-green li{
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      padding: 28px 5% 30px 5%;
      -moz-border-radius: 2px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
      border-radius: 2px;
      font-size: 30px;
      line-height: 22px;
      margin: 10px;
      background: #1fd57b;
      cursor: pointer; display:
      inline-block; zoom: 1;
      border: none;
      letter-spacing: 1px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      color: #1fd57b;
}

.pairing-prosecco-wines ul {
  text-align:center;
}
```

My question is : do you know how to extend at the maximum all the li so that it will fill in the space at the maximum ?
Thank you !

EDIT : [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wvafLdv7/4/) is the fiddle with the solution

Comment: any fiddle available ?

Comment: Ah sorry, [here it is](http://jsfiddle.net/wvafLdv7/4/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use either **[display:table](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GpdhF)** or **[display:flex;](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EKdmF)**

table layout example:

```
.list-green {
   padding:0;
   margin:auto;
   display:table;
   width:100%;
   border-spacing:10px;
 }
 .list-green li {
   display:table-cell;
 }
```

flex example

```
 .list-green {
   padding:0;
   width:100%;
   margin:0 auto;
   display:flex;
   border-spacing:10px;
 }
 .list-green li {
flex:auto;/* or 1 */
 }
```

Comment: Indeed it works ! It's a good idea, can you help me to change the title of my post in order to be easy to understand ? You can check the result [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wvafLdv7/4/)

Comment: @Clemzd would:  **how to expand childs to fill entire row ?**  will do ? (not too sure about my english)